# Which class is added while sorting?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

As you know, on jQuery UI Dragable interaction, the element being dragged gets `.ui-draggable-dragging` class. Is there anything like this for sorting?

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/teknoblogo/m6gWj/). I want to change element's background-color while dragging. Which class is added while element is dragging? `.ui-sortable-dragging`?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I found the answer myself: `.ui-sortable-helper`

Comment: is it configurable which class is applied?

Comment: @ChrisDaMour you could use the start and stop events and do something like this: http://nopaste.info/0b945edfb1.html

Comment: adding class to item results in error on drop: placeholder is not removed.

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for exactly this in the JQuery-UI API documentation but couldn't find it.  Does anyone know if this is officially documented anywhere?

Comment: How did you figure that out ?